# How to prevent Azure ML Studio from converting a feature column to DateTime while importing a dataset

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, kaggle, ml-studio

I’m having some issues trying to load a dataset in Azure ML Studio, a dataset containing a column that looks like a DateTime, but is in fact a string. Azure ML Studio converts the values to DateTimes internally, and no amount of wrangling seems to convince it of the that they’re in fact strings.

This is an issue, because during conversion the values lose precision and start appearing as duplicates whereas in fact they are unique. Does anybody know if ML Studio can be configured not to infer data types for columns while importing a dataset?

Now, for the long(er) story :)

I’m working here with a public dataset - specifically [Kaggle’s New York City Fare Prediction](https://www.kaggle.com/c/new-york-city-taxi-fare-prediction) competition. I wanted to see if I could do a quick-and-dirty solution using Azure ML Studio, however the dataset’s unique key values are of the form

    `2015-01-27 13:08:24.0000003
    2015-01-27 13:08:24.0000002
    2011-10-06 12:10:20.0000001`

and so on.

When importing them in my experiment the key values get converted to DateTime, making them no longer unique, even though they’re unique in the csv. Needless to say, this prevents me from submitting any solution to Kaggle, since I can’t identify the rows uniquely :).

I’ve tried the following:

- edit the metadata of the dataset after it has been loaded and setting the data type of the column to string, but this doesn’t do much as the precision has already been lost
- import the dataset from an Azure blob, convert it to csv and then loading it in Jupyter/Python - this brings me the same (duplicated) keys.
- loading the dataset locally with pandas works, as expected.

I’ve reproduced this behavior with both the big, 5.5GB `train` dataset, but also with the more manageable `sample_submission` dataset.

Curious to know if there is some sort of workaround to tell ML Studio not to try converting this column while loading the dataset. I'm looking here specifically for Azure ML Studio-only solutions, as I don't want to do any preprocessing on the dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried with you sample data and here is my quick and dirty solution:
1) Add any symbol (I've added the '#') in front of each date
2) Load it to AML Studio (it is now considered as a string feature)
3) Add a Python/R component to remove the '#' symbol and explicitly convert the column to string (as.string(columnname) or str(columnname))

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, guess that’s the only way to do this at the moment. Was looking for a solution that didn’t include any pre-processing (not even prepending text characters to the key values :) ), I take it that we’ll have to wait a while until that’s possible.